# Send additional headers to System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, http, webbrowser-control

I am trying to send additional headers to my web site using:

```
public void Navigate(string urlString,
    string targetFrameName,
    byte[] postData,
    string additionalHeaders);`
```

I am adding multiple headers by calling

```
foreach (var key in additionalHeaders.Keys)
{
    builder.AppendFormat(@"{0}: {1}\r\n", key, additionalHeaders[key]);
}
```

where I add `\r\n` to separate out the headers. The problem is that in fiddler I can see the header being sent as `H1: v1\r\nH2: v2` instead of separate entries

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `@` so `\r\n` don't turn to new line.
Change:

```
foreach (var key in additionalHeaders.Keys)
{
    builder.AppendFormat(@"{0}: {1}\r\n", key, additionalHeaders[key]);
}
```

To:

```
foreach (var key in additionalHeaders.Keys)
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\r\n", key, additionalHeaders[key]);
}
```

Comment: *breaks down and starts crying*... THIS was it. God I feel sooooooooo sad.